# Binding showing type rather than value

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding, xaml, windows-phone-7

Hey.
 I've having some trouble with binding in XAML. I have a list of `Player` objects. I would like this list to be bound to a ListBox and display the `Name` of the `Player`. At the moment, the List box is being filled with `Red.Player` (i.e. the object type and namespace). My resource dictionary style looks like this:

```
<Style x:Key="PlayerListBox" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Border x:Name="LayoutRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}" d:DesignWidth="231" d:DesignHeight="50">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource TransparentBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding}" FontSize="29.333" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I guess the main part is this:

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding}" FontSize="29.333" TextAlignment="Center"/>
```

I tried using `Text="{Binding Name}"` but then nothing shows up at all. I'm setting the `ItemsSource` when the user selected a player:

```
PlayerList.ItemsSource = ListofPlayers;
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is Name a public property on the type you've bound to?

ie

```
public class Person
{
    string name;
    int age;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    public int Age
    {
        get { return age; }
        set { age = value; }
    }

}
```

Sample project here demonstrating binding data to a listbox.

[binding a Linq datasource to a listbox](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/0baf666f-5797-4917-9228-0a66dead8f72)

Comment: hey. Yes, it's a public property. Within the Player class, I have this:`public string Name { get; set; }`

Comment: D'oh, been working too long. I just had a property without using the private field, so I didn't have `return name;`. Thanks. (will accept answer in 5 mins, when I can :)

Comment: Glad it's resolved for you. Note you can use prop snippets in VS to help with this stuff rather than manually typing.

Answer (score 1):

Use de `ListBox.ItemTemplate` property to set how the data is shown with respect to properties.

Eg.

```
<ListBox.DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want use `{Binding}` without specifying a property, you can override ToString() to return the text you want to display.